# React Custom useRequest Hook causes MemoryLeak

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memory-leaks, react-hooks

I'm working on a project that uses a **custom hook** `useRequest` to fetch data from server.

The implementation is

```
const useRequest = ({ url }) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(null);
  const [apiData, setApiData] = React.useState({});

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const abortController = new AbortController();

    fetch(url, {
      headers: headers,
      signal: abortController.signal,
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        if (data.status_message) {
          throw Error(data.status_message);
        }
        setApiData(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(err);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });

    return function cleanup() {
      abortController.abort();
    };
  }, [url]);
  return { isLoading, apiData, error };
};

export default useRequest;
```

I don't know why but sometimes **it throws memory-leak error.** Can someone help why it is so?

Components where I'm using the `useRequest` hook:

**1) ItemInfo Component-**

```
function Item() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const { path } = useRouteMatch();
  const type = path.split("/")[1];

  const { isLoading, apiData, error } = useRequest({
    url: request.getItemData(id, type),
  });
  if (error) return <NotFound error={error} />;

  if (isLoading) return <Loader />;
  const RowComp = withRow(Row);

  return (
    <div className="itemInfo">
      {apiData && (
        <>
          <Banner data={apiData} />
          <div className="itemInfo__wrapper">
            <div className="itemInfo__overview">
              <h2>Overview</h2>
              <p>{apiData.overview}</p>
            </div>
            <Details details={apiData} />
            <RowComp title="Cast" url={request.getCast(type, id)} />
            {type === "movie" && apiData.belongs_to_collection && (
              <RowComp
                url={request.getCollection(apiData.belongs_to_collection.id)}
                title="Collections"
              />
            )}
            {type === "tv" && apiData.seasons && (
              <Row results={apiData.seasons} title="Seasons" />
            )}
            <RowComp
              url={request.getRecommendations(id, type)}
              title="Recommendations"
            />
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Item;
```

**2)** An **HOC**

```
function withRow(WrappedComponent) {
  const HOC = ({ url, title }) => {
    const { isLoading, apiData } = useRequest({ url });
    const results = apiData.results || apiData.parts || apiData.cast;
    return (
      <>
        {isLoading && <Loader />}
        {results && <WrappedComponent results={results} title={title} />}
      </>
    );
  };
  HOC.propTypes = {
    url: PropTypes.string,
    title: PropTypes.string,
  };
  return HOC;
}
```

**The HOC component mainly logs the error but sometime ItemInfo Component also logs Memory Leak error**
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think if the request is cancelled, the `.catch` handler calls `setError`, which might happen after the component unmounted already (as cancellation happens on unmount). Can you add a log into the `.catch` to check this?

Comment: I does catch the error. This is the log ```DOMException: The user aborted a request.``` But before this log, there is the memory leak error.

Comment: Huh, were is that log coming from?

Comment: The ```.catch``` block, I added a ```console.log``` to it.

Comment: Ah, Okay, did you add the log before the `setError` or afterwards? So could that be the cause?

Comment: After the ```SetError``` method. It's ```.catch((err) => {
        setError(err);
        setIsLoading(false);
        console.log(err);
      });```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what happens:

1.) The components unmount.

2.) Effect cleanups happen (directly afterwards, synchronously), and `abortController.abort();` gets called. From now on no `setState` shall be called on the component.

3.) Either `fetch(...)` or `res.json()` (?) throw the exception, and the Promise gets rejected

4.) In a microtask, the `.catch` callback runs, and `setError` and `setIsLoading` get called. As the component does not exist anymore, the error you see is raised.

In my eyes cleaning up the fetch should be silent, so `AbortError`s should be supressed:

```
.catch(error => {
   // If the component is cleaned up, and the fetch() is aborted, silently stop as nobody is listening to our error anyways
   if(error.name === "ABORT_ERR") return;
   // In other cases, raise error to component:
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I too got this. Its because calling```setState``` in the ```.catch()``` block. Thanks for your help.